# Turn off auto-responder messages

Tags: twilio, unsubscribe

Currently Twilio sends auto responder messages for people that unsubscribe from an SMS campaign. This is something we want to handle on our end. So currently we send a message as does twilio. Is there a way to turn off twilio auto responders?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot turn these off especially the keyword stop, only short codes allow this.

to customize the opt-in/opt-out/help auto responders you will need to create a messaging service and add number resource under it. afterwards you should be able to customize it as you like. the feature is under your messaging service resource , called opt-out management.

as far as i know you cannot accomplish this without a messaging service.

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034798533-Getting-Started-with-Advanced-Opt-Out-for-Messaging-Services